# Mount locally served smb/afp share

Tags: macos, high-sierra, smb, file-sharing, afp

For some of my workflows, I need to mount a folder somewhere else, and this process should be transparent, meaning symbolic links don't work. Because macOS don't support `mount --bind` and the `nullfs` macOS uses to isolate quarantined programs aren't exposed to the end user, I use `sshfs`, but it's very slow to mount and hangs the system for a while during the mounting process.

Since I have served smb/afp connections from my macbook before, I think maybe that will solve the problem. Trying to mount `smb://localhost` resulted in the error `The file server is available on your computer. Access the volumes and files locally`. I assume this failed because Apple think that there is no reason to mount a folder already present on your computer somewhere else on your computer, but I do have valid reasons for doing so.

Trying to do this in the Terminal brings up even weirder errors. (To avoid permission errors, I'm doing this is a root shell).

Trying with `afp`:

```
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]# mount_afp afp://localhost /tmp/data
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 22, errno is 3
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]# mount_afp -i afp://localhost /tmp/data
User: tmp
Password:
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 22, errno is 3
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]# mount_afp -i afp://localhost /tmp/data
User: guest
Password:
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 22, errno is 3
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]# mount_afp -i afp://localhost /tmp/data
User: root
Password:
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 22, errno is 3
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]# mount_afp -i afp://localhost /tmp/data^C
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]#
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]# mount_afp -i afp://tmp:password/localhost /tmp/data
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [1]# mount_afp -i afp://tmp:password@localhost /tmp/data
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 22, errno is 3
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]# mount_afp -i afp://guest@localhost /tmp/data
Password:
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 22, errno is 3
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [22]# mount_afp -i afp://tmp:password@localhost/data /tmp/data
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error -5023, errno is -5023
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [97]# mount_afp -i afp://tmp:password@localhost/CCC1 /tmp/data
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error -5023, errno is -5023
```

Trying with `smb`:

```
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~# mount_smbfs -o nobrowse,soft //localhost /tmp/datra
mount_smbfs: could not find mount point /private/tmp/datra: No such file or directory
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [71]# mount_smbfs -o nobrowse,soft //localhost /tmp/data
Password for localhost:
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [77]#
mount_smbfs -o nobrowse,soft //tmp:passwd@localhost /tmp/data
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [77]#
mount_smbfs -o nobrowse,soft //tmp:passwd@localhost/data /tmp/data
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro ~ [77]# mount -t smbfs //tmp:passwd@localhost/data /tmp/data
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
```

How can I tell if this is something Apple is explicitly trying to prevent me from doing, due to wrong commands/arguments, or due to `smb`/`afp` configuration errors?

Note: accessing `smb` shares served from my macbook from a Windows computer on the same network works without any problems.

Comment: Perhaps, you could explain what is your valid reason for doing this.

Comment: Change where applications put their data.

Comment: Do you mean like changing the location of your home folder?

Comment: Something like that, but for folders in `~/Library/Application Support/com.app.identifier`